# Scrapy Xpath with text() equal to

Tags: scrapy

```
    import scrapy
    example='<div class="ParamText"><span>OWNER APP</span></div>
<div class="ParamText"><span>OWNER</span></div>
<div class="ParamText"><span>OWNER NAME</span></div>'
    scrapy.Selector(text=example).xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[contains(text(),"OWNER")]').extract_first()
```

Here I need to scrape OWNER only sometimes 3 span I will get OWNER

**output:**

I am getting: OWNER APP

I want: OWNER

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `^OWNER$` to match spans containing only `OWNER`.

Replace `contains(text(),"OWNER")` with [`re:test(text(),"^OWNER$")`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions).

The advantage of regular expressions is that you could also allow for spaces (`^\s*OWNER\s*$`) or support different letter cases (`(?i)^OWNER$`).

Comment: I am afraid this is not supported in current version of scrapy. They use 1.0 version, not 2.0 with regexp's.

Comment: I’ve linked the re:test reference to the Scrapy documentation. Scrapy includes an XPath 1.0 extension that adds regular expression support.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrapy.Selector(text=example).xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/text()').extract()[1]
```

Comment: You may do it like: `scrapy.Selector(text=example).xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span/text()').extract_first().split(' ')[0]` This will split the str into an array and select the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can select by text equation like `scrapy.Selector(text=txt).xpath('//*[@class="ParamText"]/span[text()="OWNER"]').get()` or without span details, it will give you the first one: `scrapy.Selector(text=txt).css('div.ParamText span').get()`